# Start working on pandas and getting erroe on thos

Tags: pandas

I have just started my work on pandas. Currently I'm working on a dataset of NETFLIX.

In this dataset I want to add a new column which contains the total number of cast members in that particular movie or tv show. I can calculate the cast individually but I want to calculate all of them. Can someone help me to write this code ?
Here is what I'm trying to do:

link https://www.kaggle.com/datasets/shivamb/netflix-shows?

```
def set_cast(val):
    if val is None:
        return 0
    if val == 'None':
        return 0
    return len(val.split(', '))
data['num_of_cast'] = data['cast'].apply(set_cast)
```

getting these error

> return SeriesApply(self, func, convert_dtype, args, kwargs).apply()
> 'float' object has no attribute 'split'

Comment: Please modify your question in such a way that it is more readable. Also add code that you have tried to do, and specify exactly what your problem is. The SO community does not usually welcome questions that are not well crafted and have not been worked on.

Comment: You have float values or NaNs in `data['cast']`. It would be great to have a link to the mentioned dataset

Comment: can anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

In your dataset the first column are some statistics. Maybe they are the flout values that causes the error.

[image: picture of yourdataset]

Try skipping the first column. Maybe like this:

```
data['num_of_cast'] = [set_cast(x) for x in data['cast'] if data['cast'].index(x) >=1]
```

Instead of this:

```
data['num_of_cast'] = data['cast'].apply(set_cast)
```